# How can I Copy to clipboard, a ListView's multiple selected items?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This code is working for one single selected item:
In the top:

```
ContextMenuStrip menuStrip;
```

Then in the constructor:

```
menuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
menuStrip.ItemClicked += menuStrip_ItemClicked;
menuStrip.Items.Add("Cut");
menuStrip.Items.Add("Copy");
menuStrip.Items.Add("Paste");
```

The `menuStrip` itemclicked event:

```
ListViewItem item;
        private void menuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Copy")
            {
                Clipboard.SetText(item.SubItems[1].Text);

            }
        }
```

Then the `ListView` mouse click event:

```
private void lstDisplayHardware_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                item = lstDisplayHardware.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
                menuStrip.Show(lstDisplayHardware, e.Location);
            }
        }
```

This code is working for single selected item.
For example I click on an item in the `ListView`, right click on the item and select `Copy`: the selected item's subitem is copied to the Clipboard.

But now I want to do the same thing for multiple selection.

So if I use Ctrl+Left mouse click and for example selected 4 items and invoke `Copy` command from the context menu, I expect all subitems of the 4 selected items text to be copied into the Clipboard.

For example I have these items:

danny    hello world 
daniel   hi all 
dan      rain today 
daniels  sunny day

I select the items:

danny
daniel
dan 
daniels

Then right click and click on Copy.
When I `paste` anywhere from the clipboard I want it to show:

hello world
hi all
rain today
sunny day

All of the sub items of the selected items in the same order and format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you have to enable multiselect:

```
ListView1.MultiSelect = true;
```

Then, you can get selected items with:

```
private void menuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection selectedItems = 
    ListView1.SelectedItems;
    if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Copy")
    {
         String text = "";
         foreach ( ListViewItem item in selectedItems )
         {
              text += item.SubItems[1].Text;
         }
         Clipboard.SetText(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
    private void listBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            CopyListBox(listBox1);
        }
    }

    public void CopyListBox(ListBox list)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string item in list.SelectedItems)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(item);
        }

        Clipboard.SetDataObject(sb.ToString());

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

For ListView, not ListBox code will be:

```
    private void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            CopyListBox(listView1);
        }
    }
    public void CopyListBox(ListView list)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in list.SelectedItems)
        {
            ListViewItem l = item as ListViewItem;
            if (l != null)
                foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem sub in l.SubItems)
                    sb.Append(sub.Text+"\t");
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(sb.ToString());

    }
```